# Weird box on window drag to maximize

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a VM and when i drag a corner of a window or an entire window to the edges of the screen i see an empty box that appears and disappears and it messes with the maximize function of the window making it quite unusable and jumping. Is this a bug or something is missing? i've attached a [recording of the issue](https://youtu.be/GJyov1MLc6A). Thank you all